# Startup device error status: { DRDY ERR } and error: { ABRT }. What could it be?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, sata

Startup error photos:

[image]

```
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x5
ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
ata1.00: cmd c8/00:20:00:c1:e7/00:00:00:00:00/ee tag 0 dma 16384 in
         res 51/04:20:00:c1:e7/00:00:00:00:00/ee Emask 0x1 (device error)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your hard disk is not coming to ready status. I'd check the power and data connections to the drive first. You might have a bad hard drive. Cheers, Al

Comment: Facing similar issue in 18.04, but, it is happening after I wake up laptop from sleep (without AC power). It is Dell 3460 with hard-disk encrypted using Dell drive encryption. However, windows 10 on other partition has no such issue waking up.

Comment: did you solve this? I am having the same issue in 18.04 Desktop machine

Answer (score 0):

Changing SATA settings from IDE to AHCI in BIOS worked for me.

Comment: Mine is already AHCI

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was ... the connector was not properly plugged in.