# How to find out if I have two Ubuntu installed on my PC?

Tags: mount, home-directory, partitioning

I suspect I have multiple Ubuntu installations on different partitions on my PC. But how do I find out about them? Which command to use?

Output of

```
 sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

is

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT            LABEL
sda           931.5G                       
├─sda1 ext4     660G /home/sda1_mountpoint 709G
├─sda2            1K                       
├─sda5 swap     7.7G [SWAP]                
├─sda6 vfat   123.4G /data124G             132G
├─sda7 ext4    74.3G /data73G              80G
└─sda8 ext4    66.1G /                     
sdb    ext4   931.5G                       
└─sdb1 ext4   931.5G /data1T               data1T
sr0            1024M
```

and Output of

```
sudo parted -l
```

is

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      32.3kB  709GB   709GB   primary   ext4
 2      709GB   1000GB  291GB   extended
 7      709GB   788GB   79.7GB  logical   ext4
 6      788GB   921GB   132GB   logical   fat32
 8      921GB   992GB   71.0GB  logical   ext4
 5      992GB   1000GB  8266MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA ST1000DM003-1ER1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4
```

**Background info** - Some problem occurred when PC was not restarting. It was stuck in [login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and [similar error to this was occuring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839347/startup-device-error-status-drdy-err-and-error-abrt-what-could-it-be). I did `ctrl-alt-f1` . I found that user's home directory was missing i.e/ `/home/` was empty! I did mkdir `/home/user` and copied an old backuped home directory there and restarted. It started fine. Later I mounted `sda1` at `/home/sda1_mountpoint`. It gave `missing superblock` error. I had to do `fsck`, then it mounted. the missing home directory was found in `sda1` .

So I think problem is with multiple installations. Also notice that none of the output of lsblk is `/home`.

**EDIT** After reading comments, I mounted `sda1` to `/home` instead of `/home/sda1_mountpoint`

Output of `etc/fstab` is

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=10138724-bb55-4d41-b8f8-81fc42ec1a84 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=7d10a86a-3139-45af-bfc5-3dbb26a3e767 none            swap    sw              0       0
# sda1
UUID=b50f72de-3b8b-4453-a743-cc37f06055a5 /home           ext4   defaults    0    2 
# sda6
UUID=DBA5-EDA5 /data124G                                    vfat   defaults 0 0  
# sda7
UUID=01e6d118-230d-4f22-a528-3e7ff06aef39 /data73G          ext4 defaults 0 0
# sdb1
UUID=a92ea8c4-c810-4c06-8586-285bed30ea3f /data1T          ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Output of `mount` command is

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=12301796k,nr_inodes=3075449,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=2464372k,mode=755)
/dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=26,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /data1T type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda6 on /data124G type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda7 on /data73G type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/user/108 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=2464372k,mode=700,uid=108,gid=114)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/108/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=108,group_id=114)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=2464372k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Comment: I would try to search for some basic files like `fstab` (normally located in `/etc`) whether they appear twice (or more): `find / -name fstab 2> /dev/null`

Comment: @Melebius `sudo find / -type f -name fstab` outputs
`/lib/init/fstab`;
`/usr/share/doc/mount/examples/fstab`;
`/usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/fstab`;
`/etc/fstab`

Comment: Same result here. That’s why I haven’t posted my advice as an answer, I hadn’t checked it before. However, this suggests the OS is installed only once in your case, too. What makes you think there are multiple instances?

Comment: @Melebius some problem occurred when PC was not restarting. I did `ctrl-alt-f1` . I found that user's home directory was missing. I did mkdir `/home/user` and copied an old backuped home directory there and restarted. Later I mounted `sda1` at `/home/sda1_mountpoint`. It gave `missing superblock` error. I had to do `fsck`, then it mounted. the missing home directory was found in `sda1` .

So I think problem is with multiple installations. Also notice that none of the output of lsblk is `/home`. What is your output of `lsblk`?

Comment: IMHO posting my `lsblk` would be useless, I have much different partition setup. I am still not understanding where could the other installation come from. Have you created another `/home` partition? Well, that’s not another OS installation, just another copy of user data. _“notice that none of the output of lsblk is `/home`”_ You don’t need a separate home partition, I don’t have one, too.

Comment: @Melebius you may be right. Note that my `sda8` is mounted on `/`. Does that mean `/home/user` should be kept inside `sda8`? I am very confused by my partitions. I think my old `/home/user` was in `sda1` which is why when `sda1` was not mounted the users home directory was missing.

Comment: Yes, if you created it using `mkdir` inside the root partition, which is `sda8` in your case. You should also post the output of plain `mount` command (without parameters) and the contents of the file `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @Melebius Thanks. I added output of these two files/commands in OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no sign that you have two Ubuntu installations on your hard drive. If there were multiple Linux installation and you had all meaningful partitions mounted (as you indeed have according to the `lsblk` output), you would get duplicate results if you tried to find essential system files like `shadow` (normally located in `/etc/`).

```
find / -type f -name shadow 2> /dev/null
```

## Restoring the original `/home` contents

The only thing you may have duplicated is the home folder:

> I found that user's home directory was missing i.e/ `/home/` was empty! I did mkdir `/home/user` and copied an old backuped home directory there and restarted.

However, you seem to have discovered the correct solution already:

> Later I mounted `sda1` at `/home/sda1_mountpoint`. It gave `missing superblock` error. I had to do `fsck`, then it mounted. the missing home directory was found in `sda1`.

Since the mount is still present in your `/etc/fstab`,

```
# sda1
UUID=b50f72de-3b8b-4453-a743-cc37f06055a5 /home           ext4   defaults    0    2
```

it should mount automatically on next reboot. If not, the UUID has probably changed, so you should update it in this file. You can get the current UUID using `blkid`:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda1
```

## Removing the duplicated `/home` contents

The only remaining task is to get rid of the duplicate home folder contents. The contents of `/home` on the root partition are still present on the disk, although it’s overlaid using `mount`. This is not necessary but the data are still occupying your disk space… To access them, mount the original contents elsewhere, e.g. to `/mnt`:

```
sudo mount --bind /home /mnt
```

Then open the `/mnt` directory, you should see the contents of your temporary `/home` there. Delete or move them and unmount it:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

## References

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658/linux-how-can-i-view-all-uuids-for-all-available-disks-on-my-system
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/access-to-original-contents-of-mount-point
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251090/why-does-mount-happen-over-an-existing-directory

Comment: Thanks, if indeed two ubuntu were installed, what output would be different?

Comment: @user13107 I finally finished the test suggested in [my first comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028014/how-to-find-out-if-i-have-two-ubuntu-installed-on-my-pc/1028042#comment1671222_1028014). See updated answer.