# Problem while installing Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Tags: 16.04, boot, system

I have an Acer Aspire 3100 and here is what I got when I try to install Ubuntu on it. ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osn6s.jpg))

Hardware,
Processor: Mobile AMD Sempron(tm) processor 3400+ 1.80ghz
Ram: 3GB
System type: 32Bit

Comment: You should check your hard disk surface and SMART for errors from LiveCD.

Comment: Hi. thank you for your comment but how can i do so ?

Comment: Even when i tried a live cd it does the same thing. First it does this error for a while, then it show up the ubuntu and charge for a really long time and finaly it comes but crashes with an error message.

Comment: Try these: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/321277/how-do-i-recover-from-a-read-dma-bootup-error - https://askubuntu.com/questions/839347/startup-device-error-status-drdy-err-and-error-abrt-what-could-it-be